# How do I use webpack to be able to require an HTML document with inlined CSS, JS and PNG

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I have template folders full of arbitrary css/html/js/image files.  I want to be able to access them via require:

```
var someHtml = require('./templateFolder/foo.html');
```

Here, `foo.html` contains references to `foo.png`, `foo.css`, and `foo.js`, I want them all inlined in the html document itself, in base64 encoding, style tags, and script tags, respectively. Is this possible?  If so what would the webpack configuration look like?

EDIT: Further Context

I want this

```
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="bar.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body
</html>
```

to be transformed into this:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <style> Contents of foo.css </style>
      <script> Contents of bar.js</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body
</html>
```

In other words, I want a each html file and all of its resources to be transformed into a single html file.  I don't necessarily have a lot of control as to what the html files look like.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use the `html-loader` for webpack for your use case:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader

A sample webpack.config file would include:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [ {
      loader: 'html-loader',
      options: {
        minimize: true
      }
    }],
  }]
}
```

You should then be able to require a html file you want with `require("html-loader!./file.html");`

For more information look up the link above!

---

Edit:
To automatically inline images for example you can make use of the `attrs` parameter:

> By default every local  is required (require('./image.png')). You may need to specify loaders for images in your configuration (recommended file-loader or url-loader).
>
> You can specify which tag-attribute combination should be processed by this loader via the query parameter attrs. Pass an array or a space-separated list of : combinations. (Default: attrs=img:src)

---

Edit:
To do the same for stylesheet links and js you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-inline-source-webpack-plugin

Comment: Hmm, will this inline css, js, and pngs?

Comment: I think I must have asked the question incorrectly.  I want something like this from the html: 

`<script src="foo.js"> `

to look like this 

`<script> /*contents of foo.js */ </script>`

And link:href to do something similar.  Any thoughts?